# Why does the SDTT tell me that the image field is missing?

Tags: html, images, schema.org, drupal, rdfa

I created a recipe on Drupal 8. When I [test my page](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=fr#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.s1biose.com%2Ffr%2Frecette%2Fmini-brochettes-de-jambon-melon-fromage) with Google Structured Data Testing Tool, it tells me that the image field is missing:

[image]

Yet when I open the link of the image in my internet browser, the image is displayed.

Why does the Google tool tell me that the image field is missing?

Example markup:

```html
<img property="schema:image" src="image.jpg" alt="…" typeof="foaf:Image" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The error the SDTT reports is only for getting Google’s Article rich result. If you don’t want to get the rich result, you can ignore the error.

For getting Google’s Article rich result, the value for `image` needs to be either a URL, or an Schema.org `ImageObject`.

So you can either remove the FOAF `Image` type, so that you only provide a URL value:

```html
<img property="schema:image" src="image.jpg" alt="…" />
```

Or you can provide an Schema.org `ImageObject` + FOAF `Image` item:

```html
<div typeof="schema:Article">
  <div property="schema:image" typeof="foaf:Image schema:ImageObject">
    <img property="schema:contentUrl schema:url" src="image.jpg" alt="…" />
  </div>
</div>
```

(You can ignore the error that Google’s SDTT doesn’t know the FOAF `Image` type; the tool mostly knows only Schema.org, but it’s perfectly fine to use other vocabularies.)

Answer (score 0):

In general: This is a kind of messy code, which comes from the Drupal core and extensions. Don't know, how to deal with it. I would firstly get rid of any extension, which implements structured data. Then i would write a clean structured data code, which reflects my needs. Then i would try to implement it.

Your image: in the test you run **the image you are talking about is recognized as an image**:

[image]

You should clean up you structured data code and tie the meaningful data types (Recipe, Article and Person) to the one single entity together.